# Label not moving up when focused in BasicTextField

Tags: android, kotlin, material-ui, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield

Label not moving up when I focus on the BasicTextField but it's only moving up when I start typing.
Here is the BasicTextField I'm using
I'm using the same properties of the TextField. Wondering why TextField works like this and BasicTextField which Textfield uses internally doesn't

```
BasicTextField(
        value = value,
        modifier = Modifier
          .onFocusChanged { isFocused = it.isFocused }
          .focusRequester(focusRequester)
          .background(colors.backgroundColor(enabled).value, shape)
          .indicatorLine(enabled, isError, interactionSource, colors)
          .defaultMinSize(
            minWidth = TextFieldDefaults.MinWidth,
            minHeight = TextFieldDefaults.MinHeight
          ),
        onValueChange = { newText ->
          if (newText.length <= characterLimit || !isTextLimiterVisible) onValueChange(newText)
        },
        enabled = enabled,
        textStyle = AppTheme.Typography.Body.medium.merge(TextStyle(color = colors.textColor(enabled).value)),
        cursorBrush = SolidColor(colors.cursorColor(isError).value),
        visualTransformation = VisualTransformation.None,
        keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(),
        maxLines = TEXT_FIELD_MAX_LINES,
        decorationBox = @Composable { innerTextField ->
          TextFieldDefaults.TextFieldDecorationBox(
            value = value,
            innerTextField = innerTextField,
            enabled = enabled,
            placeholder = {
              BodySmall(text = placeholder, color = AppTheme.Colors.Surface.onSurfaceVariant)
            },
            label = {
              BodyMedium(
                text = label,
                color = if (enabled) {
                  AppTheme.Colors.Surface.onSurfaceVariant
                } else {
                  AppTheme.Colors.Surface.onSurface.level3()
                },
                modifier = Modifier.graphicsLayer {
                  transformOrigin = TransformOrigin(LABEL_SCALE_ORIGIN_X, LABEL_SCALE_ORIGIN_Y)
                  scaleX = labelScale
                  scaleY = labelScale
                }
              )
            },
            singleLine = false,
            isError = isError,
            visualTransformation = VisualTransformation.None,
            interactionSource = interactionSource,
            colors = colors,
          )
```

Basically using the same implementation as TextField

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the same `interactionSource` to the `BasicTextField`

```
BasicTextField(
    //...
    interactionSource = interactionSource,
    decorationBox = @Composable { innerTextField ->
        TextFieldDefaults.TextFieldDecorationBox(
            //...
            interactionSource = interactionSource,
        )
    }
)
```